# Python bisection query

Tags: python, bisection

I've just started python and OCW seemed like a pretty popular choice to start. However i'm stuck at a problem set wherein given a set of params you have to figure out the amount of salary you have to save in a given month. it uses bisection search which i've implemented, but my code doesn't seem to give the correct answer.

The salary is incremented by 7% every 6 months and there's an annual 4% return on savings credited at the end of month. The % savings should stop when the total savings is within $100 of the down payment requirement.

```
cost = int(1000000)
down_payment = float(0.25 * cost)
current_savings = 0
r = 0.04
annual_salary = int(150000)
a = annual_salary
months = 0
semi_raise = 0.07
epsilon = 100
high = 1.0
def savings(a, current_savings, portion, down_payment):
    for m in range(1, 37):
        if m%6 == 0 and m>0:
            a = a * (1+semi_raise)
        current_savings = current_savings + (a/12 * portion) + (current_savings * r)
        return (current_savings)
while abs(current_savings-down_payment) >= 100:
    portion = float((high+low)/2)
    annual_salary = a
    current_savings = 0.0
    current_savings = savings(a, current_savings, portion, down_payment)
    if current_savings < down_payment:
        low = portion
    elif current_savings > down_payment:
        high = portion
    else:
        print("not enough savings")
print("Best", "%.4f" %portion)
```

for this case i'm getting 0.2239 vs 0.4411 as given in the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check that the savings you calculate are correct ? 
I would have updated the annual salary after after having calculated my current savings like that:

```
def savings(a, current_savings, portion, down_payment):
    for m in range(1, 37):
        current_savings = current_savings + a/12 * portion + current_savings * r
        if m % 6 == 0 and m>0:
            a = a * (1+semi_raise)
    return (current_savings)
```

Comment: Yes, it has a minor effect (.2263 vs .2239), but nowhere close to the answer